# Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string' - TypeScript error

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, types

TS error "Object is undefined"

Trying to access "userid" from my headers.
It keeps throwing the error "Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'."

[image]

[image: undefined]

When I have already defined userid as string or undefined why does this error pop up??
Any idea anyone????

**Update:**
Adding a check before accessing apiGateway event

```
if (apiGateway.event !== undefined) {
   const { userid } = req.apiGateway.event.headers;
} else {
   throw new badRequestException() 
}

return......
```

Comment: You are accessing apiGateway.event while apiGateway can be undefined (note the '?'). You need to check whether it's !== undefined

Comment: @zhuber please check my updated question. you mean a check like that??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Judging by your definition of `MyRequest`:

- `apiGateway` **can** be undefined
- `event` cannot be undefined
- `headers` cannot be undefined
- `userid` **can** be undefined

So right off the bat, writing `req.apiGateway.event.headers` will fail, because if `apiGateway` is undefined, then accessing `.event` on it will crash. So Typescript does not allow that.

There are three ways around this:

1. Explicitly check against it. Something like `if (req.apiGateway === undefined) { throw new badRequestException(); }`
2. If you're **certain** that it can't be `undefined`, you can force TypeScript to accept it. Write `req.apiGateway!.event`. Mind you, if `apiGateway` does happen to be undefined at runtime, you'll get an exception. So only use this if you are absolutely 100% sure that it cannot under any circumstance be undefined.
3. Accept that it can be undefined and coerce everything else to undefined as well. Write `req.apiGateway?.event` - in this case `.event` will also be considered as undefined-able. If `req.apiGateway` happens to be undefined in runtime, then `req.apiGateway?.event` will also be undefined. And so on and so forth. This means that you'll also have to add `?.` to the rest of the line: `req.apiGateway?.event?.headers`. And the result of the whole expression is ALSO undefined-able, so you'll probably need to use more undefined-checks later.

Now, for your second problem. Currently your `userid` local variable has the type `string|undefined`. That us because `req.apiGateway.event.headers.userid` is `string|undefined`. This means that at runtime it can be either a string, or undefined. However the method `updateNotification()` expects a simple `string` as its parameter. It cannot deal with undefined values. If you were to pass it undefined, who knows what would happen (probably an exception). Therefore Typescript does not allow this. And, again, you can use the above methods for dealing with it.

Answer (score 3):

always when you got this error it's good to just check if variable has some value:

```
if(!variable) return
// continue
```

after this if type of variable will be string instead of string | undefined